# Win10 Postscript/TrueType fonts from server shows 0KB

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, postscript, truetype

I'm having a problem converting from a Mac to Windows at work.

All the companies fonts are stored on a web server, and works like a charm on Mac,
However, when I try to install PostScript & TrueType fonts, it shows no extension name, and have a file size of 0KB. If I try and write the file extension, and install it says invalid font (still 0KB)
On OpenType fonts it work fine.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem? (There is hundreds of fonts that I need to install)

[image: Screenshot of file properties]

Comment: To copy Mac fonts to a PC, see https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-copy-mac-fonts-onto-a-pc

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. It's the same problem but only for PostScript files

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Get on a Mac, install Transtype trial, and convert the files, even if it gives you errors when adding them. Just do it and you should get some functional TTF or OTF files.

I managed to set up Windows 7 to render and deal with them by using GhostScript. I've downloaded Transtype (trial) on one of my coworker's Macs and it did the thing. It made TTF/OTF files from the old Type 1 files, even though the Type 1 gave Transtype errors on the Mac.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The first paragraph of your post looks like an answer (good!).  However, the second paragraph appears unrelated, perhaps even being a question or simply commentary. On this Q&A site, we strive to keep chatter to a minimum so posts can focus on solving the problem at hand. Please consider an [edit] to your post to achieve this. Thanks for contributing.